# RxSwift and UICollectionView Header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I'm using `RxSwift` with my `UIViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView`. I have tried to add a header to my collection view but this is never called:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Answer (score 9):

After a long time figuring it out I have a complete answer.  The key part depends on the RxDataSources dataSource.configureCell *and* dataSource.supplementaryViewFactory.

You will need to setup by registering your nibs normally. To make the collection view show it's header you will need to define a header size.  Using the collection flow layout allows you preserve any bindings you might have inside cells for clickhandlers and not override the rx delegate proxy RxCocoa is using internally.

In this example I have one viewModel for the whole screen which holds an RxVariable with an array of itemViewModels for each item in the collection view.

UICollectionView with headers using RxSwift, RxDataSources, and RxCocoa:

```
var disposeBag: DisposeBag? = DisposeBag()

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let dataSource = RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, ItemViewModel>>()
 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerHeaderCell()
    registerCollectionViewCell()
    setupLayout()
    bindViewModelToCollectionView()
}

private func registerHeaderCell() {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "HeaderCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderReuseId")
}

private func registerCollectionViewCell() {
    let nib = UINib(nibName:"CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellReuseId")
}

private func setupLayout(){
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
}

private func bindViewModelToCollectionView(){
    dataSource.supplementaryViewFactory = {(dataSource, collectionView, kind, indexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView in
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderReuseId", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
        header.setup()
        return header
    }
    
    dataSource.configureCell = {(datasource, collectionView, indexPath, itemViewModel) -> UICollectionViewCell in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellReuseId", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.setup()
        return cell
    } 

    viewModel.itemViewModels.asObservable().map { 
        (itemViewModels) -> [SectionModel<String, ItemViewModel>] in
       //my particular app has one big section but you can use this for mutiple sections like Sergiy's answer   
         return [SectionModel(model: "", items: itemViewModels)]
    }.bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag!)
}

deinit {
    disposeBag = nil
}
```

Comment: For this answer to make a bit more sense, your `setup()` functions should at least take the indexPath as an argument (since it's very likely that you'll want to configure the cell based on the indexPath). Better still, just put a comment there: `// Set up cell`.

Comment: That's true, the  `setup` function is here as just a placeholder for the example.  I left it in because it may not be super obvious that this is a good place to call such a function.  But yeah, if you want different cells to appear differently you would need to pass `indexPath` in there.  You can also do tricky things with type erasure to load different types of cells. Much is left out for brevity. More examples are in the RxDatasources github, however,  I added this here because I was having trouble finding a discreet example for headers specifically.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem. Solve it moving to [RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/master/Sources/RxDataSources/RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource.swift)

This type of datasource has headers/footers. Standard one [RxCollectionViewReactiveArrayDataSource](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/DataSources/RxCollectionViewReactiveArrayDataSource.swift) doesn't have headers/footers.

Even in RxCocoa [UICollectionView+Rx](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UICollectionView%2BRx.swift) extension gives RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource as example.

Example Directly from UICollectionView+Rx:

```
     let dataSource = RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, Double>>()

     let items = Observable.just([
         SectionModel(model: "First section", items: [
             1.0,
             2.0,
             3.0
         ]),
         SectionModel(model: "Second section", items: [
             1.0,
             2.0,
             3.0
         ]),
         SectionModel(model: "Third section", items: [
             1.0,
             2.0,
             3.0
         ])
     ])

     dataSource.configureCell = { (dataSource, cv, indexPath, element) in
         let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NumberCell
         cell.value?.text = "\(element) @ row \(indexPath.row)"
         return cell
     }

     items
        .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your answer, here is a link with the information you need to do that https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: I think this requires the use of RxDataSources library. Not built in to RxCocoa I don't think even though it's copied from RxCocoa.

Answer (score -3):

It has nothing to do with `RxSwift`, unless you're using [`RxDataSources`](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources), that is.

You just aren't setting up your `UICollectionView` correctly.  Among other things:

- Make sure you define `func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int` to return something greater than `0`.
- Make sure you define `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize` to return a size that's bigger than `CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)`.
- If you're using a `nib`, then register it with `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind kind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`.  Or, if you're creating it programmatically, then register it with `func register(_ viewClass: AnyClass?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind elementKind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it did not help. My assumption was that func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) is defined in UICollectionViewDataSource protocol and it is implemented by RxSwift. What else it could be? Maybe I should update my question with more information?

Comment: I don't think adding more information would help, since you'd basically have to hand over all of your code. I'd recommend checking out a `UICollectionView` tutorial and follow it exactly to make sure that you get something working as a base.  Then modify it from there.